# Get nested parent

Tags: android

I have Views nested like this

```
FrameLayout
  CardView
    LinearLayout
      LinearLayout
        LinearLayout
          ImageButton
```

In the listener for the ImageButton, I set the top FrameLayout invisible.

**What's a better, more dynamic way than this?**

```
public void onButtonClicked(View view) {
    ((FrameLayout)view
    .getParent()
    .getParent()
    .getParent()
    .getParent()
    .getParent())
    .setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: I know Fragments have a `getView()` method. I'm sure Activitys have something similar if you are trying to get the top view. Otherwise, `findViewById` works pretty well

Comment: Can you show your layout xml file code, or at least the `CardView` layout i.e. the one that you want to hide?

Answer (score 2):

In the layout file, give an `android:id="+@id/yourName"` to the view that you want it hidden, and get the view using

```
View viewToHide = findViewbyId(R.id.yourName);
```

From there, you could set the `viewToHide.setVisibility(View.GONE);`